# best way of organizing website with many php scraping entries?

Tags: php, xpath

Working with a website that contains multiple xpath scraping/echo php coding. Wondering the best way to organize and control the text being echo'd back to the site.
From what I understand about php, probably for the most control the best thing to do is create a .php with the header

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

And then create additional .php files with different names. Then, in this xhtml index, pull in the different scraped data using < ?php include 'xpath1.php';?> for ex.

Any thoughts if this would be the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Doing some testing, I can confirm this works quite well.